# Selecting an element using jquery .parent()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-traversal

I have this markup as shown below:

```
<div id="content_area">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" valign="top">
      <div id="some_id"> </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Now i want to get the div with the id **"content_area"** using the div with the id **"some_id"** and style the **"content_area"** using jquery. How can i traverse upwars using **".parent()** in this scenario?  Will the table structure be a hurdle?

Comment: Um, if it is an id, there can be only one. There would be no need to traverse the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery API closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> **`.closest( selector )` Returns: jQuery**
>
> Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that
>   matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up
>   through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 2):

The ids are unique. If they aren't, change that to class.

If they are:

```
$('#content_area').css();
```

If you change that to class:

```
$('#some_id').parent('.content_area').css();
```

Comment: so the table structure will not be a problem?

Comment: @hussain nope, not at all. It's still the dom :)

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```
$("#some_id").parent();
```

Will return the element `<td width="100%" valign="top">`

---

[jQuery.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

```
$("#some_id").parents("#content_area");
```

Will return the element `<div id="content_area">`

---

[jQuery.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
$("#some_id").parents("#content_area").css({ color: "#333", height: "100%" });
```

Will style the element `<div id="content_area">` with a font color of `#333333` and a height of 100% of it's parent.

Comment: Ok you won this, I cant beat hyperlinks to the jQuery documentation :D

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it's as simple as

```
$("#some_id").parent().parent().parent().css("some-style", "value");
```

Not sure why you wouldn't want to just do this though:

```
$("#content_area").css("some-style", "value");
```

If it's because you have multiple divs with the same ID, consider switching to using classes. Each ID should only occur once on any given page.

Comment: Your first line of code uses bad approach. Its wordy, but the worst thing is that once you modify HTML stucture, it will be broken. `.parents` will go through all the parents of an element

Comment: Good point--it was just the first thing that came to mind. :)